# What are the possible states that these diodes could be in?

Tags: diodes

This is the problem circuit:
[image]

Im confused on how to treat this circuit the problem asked to graphically plot the voltage V_s = f(V_e), but i stumbled on the case where both the diodes are conducting -assuming they are ideal diodes- V_s = E and V_s = -E because they are parallel, but this is absurd right?

Comment: If V_s = E the diode is going to start to conduct, it's current, and that through R/2, is still zero. Therefore Ve(t) = 2 V_s = 2 E. The same goes for the opposite polarity.

Comment: I understand that the voltage of R/2 is non-zero because there is a current going thru it because the left diode is conducting, but i dont see why Ve(t) = 2V_s? @HarryH

Comment: Oh wait are you saying that V_s(t) = E = Ve(t)/2? due to them being parallel branches?

Comment: R - R is a voltage divider (if no current goes to/from the diodes).

Comment: @HarryH but what if one diode is conducting and the other isnt?

Comment: That's exactly what we would expect: at most 1 diode is conducting. When Ve(t) is high enough (>= 2E) then it's the left, fixing Vs(t) at E. If Ve(t) =< -2E it will be the right diode, fixing Vs(t) at -E. In between, Vs(t) = Ve(t)/2, as the two Rs act as a voltage divider and none of the diodes is conducting.

Comment: If Vs(t) = Ve(t)/2 for -2E < Ve(t) < 2E is still puzzling you, then look up "Voltage_divider" on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider .

Comment: I dont understand the logic of how you got the case Ve(t) <= -2E , when the right diode is conducting and the left isnt? ah i see where my confusion is Vs and Ve/2 are parallel and same direction? so V(s) = -E = Ve/2?

Comment: responding to your last comment, no i get it when both the diodes arent conducting we study the voltage divider because its the only active circuit that is also parallel to V_s

Comment: Vs(t) = -E = Ve(t)/2 is where the right diode starts conducting. If Ve(t) goes further negative (it's the independent variable here) Vs(t) will stay at -E.

Comment: yes i see , infinite thanks to you harry

Comment: Welcome. I hope you got it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *this is absurd right?*

Yes, it's absurd.

There is no situation when both diodes (assumed ideal) conduct at the same time: -

- \$D_{LEFT}\$ conducts when \$V_e\$ is positive and more than twice \$E\$ in magnitude
- \$D_{RIGHT}\$ conducts when \$V_e\$ is negative and more than twice \$E\$ in magnitude

Comment: how did you know the condition when each diode is conducting in relation to V_e and E?

Comment: I looked at the circuit and considered it @HellBoy

Comment: I did too but unfortunately i didnt get any idea, so what i did is consider the 4 cases first case which was absurd i had V_s = E- V_d and for the right diode, V_s = -E + V_d, which triggered the absurdity, second case D_left is conducting so V_s = E and V_e = ? idk how to use the basic laws to derive it because im confused by the parallel resistance which reside to the left to that diode.

Comment: @HellBoy use Thevenin's theorem to convert Ve and the two resistors to a single voltage source (Ve/2) and one series resistor. That gets rid of the parallel resistor and un-confuses you.

Comment: I swear my only problem is this, we start by two parallel resistances which two different current traverse them, somehow we make an equivalent resistance in which a unique current traverse it and we do our analysis based on this new resistance and somehow the results are valid in both cases? and for the thevenin voltage how would i extract it do i just disconnect the two diodes and anything that hangs on their linear circuit and just leave the two resistances in the original circuit?

Comment: @HellBoy this is a Q and A site and not a forum and I'm not going to be dragged into a forum-like conversation. If you don't know how to convert a voltage source and two resistors to a new voltage source and series resistor, you should either ask a new question or return to your text books or google it.

Comment: Sorry i quite stumble on this confusion on each problem , matter fact i did read about this in several books but i still cant understand it

Comment: Also why specifically twice more than the magnitude of E from which equation did you derive that from?

Comment: Because of the 2:1 potential divider formed by the two resistors @HellBoy also, why are you editing your question? This is a Q and A site and you don't go making changes to your question based upon what is provided in answers.

Comment: i dont understand what you mean by 2:1?

Comment: Read my full comment.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider

Comment: Ah thought i could do so, sorry my bad i didnt know that

Comment: I've rolled-back your question to its original form @HellBoy

Comment: Two resistors of equal value form a 2:1 potential divider @HellBoy